# Customizing OverLay View in MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am new to iPhone. i have a question, is it possible to change done button title and color of MPMoviePlayerController.in yes, then please send some code for that.
thanks in advance & Best Regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with MPMoviePlayerController. Try AV Foundation's AVPlayer. [Here's a good tutorial in the Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html).

You will need to provide your own, custom controls for use with AVPlayer.

Alternatively, you can try to use MPMoviePlayerController with controlStyle of MPMovieControlStyleNone. This will remove the default controls. My opinion is that the benefit of MPMoviePlayerController is that it works easily and provides the controls with very little effort. If you'll be making the controls either way, I would recommend going with the more flexible, more powerful AV Foundation.

Update 2015: if you target iOS8 or later, you might want to try AVPlayerViewController.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the title of the **DONE** button by using following line of code

```
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitle:@"doneButtonCaption"];
```

just use this line of code where you are writing code of MPMoviePlayerController